# Prevent IIS from flushing cache

Tags: caching, iis-6, flush

I'm trying to get IIS not to flush cached data, so that the loading of the pages after a period without requests can be faster. SO far I've tried this, but with any success:

- define an infinite time for the "Object Cache TTL" property;
- unchecked on IIS (version 6.0) the option "Recycle worker processes";
- unchecked on IIS the option "Shutdown worker processes after being idle..";
- set cache ActivityPeriod as "0".

What could I be missing? Is there something that is forcing cache to be flushed after some time idle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET, you can control caching with web.config settings or programatically.

Look here: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040518.htm

Comment: Is there something else I can do with IIS configurations?

Comment: Can Session State Timeout have something to do with this? It appears to be defined as 20 minutes and I think that is the time after which the cache is flushed... could it have something to do with it?